# Using links with Ember Data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model Teacher which has many Students.I want to lazy-load the students association so I use the "links" format. 
All is ok, when my JSON is:

```
"links": {
  "students": "/teacher/1/students"
}
```

But when i try to add "meta" property:

```
"links": {
  "students": {
     "href": "/teacher/1/students",
     "meta": 20,
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error while processing route: teacher Assertion Failed: You have pushed a record of type 'teacher' with 'students' as a link, but the value of that link is not a string. Error: Assertion Failed: You have pushed a record of type 'teacher' with 'students' as a link, but the value of that link is not a string.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept of meta on links in ember-data. You'll either need to modify the adapter or serializer or add it as a queryparam. I.e:

```
"links": {
  "students": {
     "href": "/teacher/1/students?meta=20"
  }
}
```

Comment: @DavidYunevich I understand that, but I read the ember-data source and it just doesn't support it (All the tests only check strings: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/json-api-adapter-test.js). It's possible that it's going to be addressed with "Improve link handling" in https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2905. Also according to the JSON spec your meta cannot be an int, it has to be an object. If you change it to an object you could try using https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thank you for detailed answer!